# Configurar JPA para reconhecer entidades e tabelas do PostgreSQL que estão em maiúsculas

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Recentemente estou atuando em um projeto que utiliza como SGBD o PostgreSQL. No banco todas as tabelas e as colunas estão em "MAIÚSCULO".

Exemplo:

CUSTOMER - ID_CUSTOMER - NAME - DESC

Na hora de mapear as entidades, estou usando a estratégia da barra invertida:

```java
    @Table(name = "\"CUSTOMER\"")
    public class Customer
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name ="\"ID_CUSTOMER\"")
        private Long idCustomer;
    }
```

Acredito que essa estratégia não seja a melhor, visto que neste projeto existem muitas tabelas e colunas. Conhecem outra forma para solucionar esse problema?

Pontos importantes:

- Não existe a possibilidade de mudar o nome das tabelas ou colunas,
  visto que essa base é do cliente e devemos seguir os padrões dele.
- Nosso projeto é desenvolvido em Java 8 e Spring DATA JPA.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja porque você está usando o MYSQL5DIALECT, tem um dialeto especifico para postgree, que acaba melhorando o naming strategy.

```java
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Espero que resolva eu problema.

Comment: Agradeço, mas não é isso. Minha configurações de bd já está assim. 
Segue minhas configurações:  


spring.datasource.password=XXX  

spring.datasource.username=XXX  

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none  

spring.datasource.platform=postgres  

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always  

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect  

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl  

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true